# Docker build fails if pip is installed and updated to 10.0.1 in a single RUN section

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

How would you explain `docker build` failure with `Dockerfile1`, and it's success with `Dockerfile2` (see below).

1)

```
// Dockerfile1

FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install python-pip python-dev build-essential && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

`docker build .` fails with the following err

```
Collecting pip
Downloading 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside 
environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
   from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update &&     apt-get -y install 
python-pip python-dev build-essential &&     pip install --upgrade pip &&     pip install --upgrade virtualenv &&     virtualenv /venv' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

However, it succeeds if we split it into two `RUN`.

2)

```
// Dockerfile2

FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install python-pip python-dev build-essential && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

The installation failure for `pip` is related to this [reported issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1141#issuecomment-381421570).  So my questions:

1. Why does `docker build` fail in the first case? If we just run those command in bash, there wont be any error.
2. Why does `docker build` succeed in the second case? How is it related to layering concept in docker?
3. Why specifying pip version in `Dockerfile1` (i.e. `pip install --upgrade pip=0.9.3`) solves the problem too?

> Update (May 6, 2018):

I've figured out the issue. What happens here is as below:

1. `apt-get -y install python-pip` installs an old version of pip whose shim script import `pip`'s main directly.
2. `pip install --upgrade pip` installs `pip 10.0.1` and moves `main` into an internal directory `_internal`. It adds its shim script to `PATH`.
3. Calling `pip` fails as it still calls the old shim script as it's path is cached. Running `hash -d pip` in between fixes the issue.

So apparently, splitting install and update into two `RUN` sections has similar effect as `hash -d pip`. Workarounds (also suggested by Andriy Maletsky) are 1) pin `pip` update to 9.0.3, or 2) install (latest) pip from source in the first place, or 3) use `hash -r` in between, or 4) use another RUN command for later use of pip.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `pip` executable (`/usr/bin/pip`) breaks while updating pip from version 9 to version 10.

Possible solutions:
1. Do not update and use pip v9
2. Do not use `apt-get` to install pip. [Download it manually](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py).

> Why does docker build fail in the first case? If we just run those command in bash, there wont be any error.

No, there will be an error. I ran those commands inside `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 bash` and got it.

> Why does docker build succeed in the second case? How is it related to layering concept in docker?

I believe you made a mistake somewhere in second RUN and it's silencing an error (in that place which you didn't provide). For example, this will work (because `;` used instead of `&&` and execution doesn't break after bad command):

```
RUN pip install --upgrade virtualenv && \
virtualenv /venv; source /venv/bin/activate
```

> Why specifying pip version in Dockerfile1 (i.e. pip install --upgrade pip=0.9.3) solves the problem too?

Because this pip bug appeared in version 10.

P.S. You should not update or manually change files you added to your system via `apt-get` (you are doing this via `pip install --upgrade pip`).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have figured out the issue. See my update.

Comment: Re your last sentence, could you explain why running `pip install --upgrade` is not recommended after installing a package with apt-get? Is it a general recommendation? Any reference that explains possible issues?

Comment: @nmoses yes, sort of general recommendation. According to Debian docs, everything under `/usr` directory, excluding `/usr/local` is under control of Debian package manager, and you should not modify that files. If you run `pip install --upgrade`, Debian won't know about it, and will very likely downgrade it back, when you run `apt-get dist-upgrade` (yes, you won't do this inside docker, but it's just a bad practice)